# OpenDKIM doesn't reject unvalidated incoming emails

Tags: postfix, opendkim

Last a few weeks I found that my OpenDKIM stopped rejecting incoming mails with no dkim-signature, bad-signature etc. Signing outgoing is OK, and according to the mail headers verifying provided, as well. That happened after updating the server's OS Archlinux (now kernel v.5.9.6-arch1-1).
Some of configs:

Opendkim:

```
AlwaysAddARHeader  yes
AuthservID         OpenDKIM-Main
LogWhy          yes
Mode            sv
On-NoSignature reject
On-BadSignature reject
On-SignatureError reject
On-KeyNotFound  reject
Socket          inet6:8891@[::1]
UMask           002
```

Postfix:

```
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = inet:[::1]:8891, inet:[::1]:8893  #last one is OpenDMARC
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

From validated mails the header concerning dkim like this:

```
Authentication-Results: OpenDKIM-Main; dkim=pass (1024-bit key) header.d=stackoverflow.email header.i=@stackoverflow.email header.b=Lq1gxzV+
```

From unvalidated, which must be rejected:

```
Authentication-Results: OpenDKIM-Main; dkim=none
```

How to fix this issue?